# Check if substring is contained anywhere in the actual string

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I have the following string:

```
$str = "A string".
```

When I use:

```
preg_match("/A string/", $str)
```

I get the match everything works perfectly fine, but I want to use the same regular expression for another string:

```
$str2 = "A test string".
```

For this case I can use:

```
"/A (test  )?string/"
```

But I want it to be more complex, it should also be able to match strings like this, for example:

```
A sttest ring
test A string
```

I mean that the substring "test " can appear anywhere in the subject.

Is it even possible to find a regular expression for this?

Comment: I'd solve it by using regex twice, first to find the `test `, and storing its position. Then I'd remove it from the string, and use another regex to find `A string`

Comment: @JaimeRodas Why storing its position?

Comment: @Shafizadeh well, only to know where it was, if you needed that information. Otherwise, you could just do both regexes

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
$str = "My test String";
    if (strpos($str, 'test') !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "A sttest ring";
$newstr = preg_replace("/\s*test\s*/", "", $str);
preg_match("/A string/", $newstr, $matches);
echo $matches ? 'true' : 'false';
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/WC66S)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function for that:

```
function containsLetters($testString, $lettersString, $caseSensitive = false, $whiteSpaces = false){
  if(!$caseSensitive){
    $testString = strtolower($testString); $lettersString = strtolower($lettersString);
  }
  if($whiteSpaces){
    $tw = $testString; $lw = $lettersString;
  }
  else{
    $tw = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $testString); $lw = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $lettersString);
  }
  $tst  = str_split($tw); $ltr = str_split($lw); $c = count($ltr); $r = array();
  foreach($ltr as $l){
    foreach($tst as $i => $t){
      if($l === $t){
        $a = array_splice($tst, $i, 1); $r[] = $a[0];
      }
    }
  }
  if(count($r) >= $c){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
$test = containsLetters('A sttest ring', 'a test string');
```

Just pass `true` to the 3rd argument to make it case sensitive. Also, pass `true` to the 4th argument to compare white spaces.